# Pagination broken by custom collection

Tags: magento-1.7, collection

Below is the code for creating a custom collection, but it is breaking pagination. It is showing only one item in pagination, When I am printing getSize() it is giving one(which is wrong), but on printing count() it is printing correct result.

```
               $sampleqry = 'select entity_id from catalog_product_entity_int as sample where sample.store_id=0 and sample.attribute_id="169" and sample.value=0';

                $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('r' => 'catalog_product_relation'), 'r.parent_id=e.entity_id', array());
                $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('s' => 'sales_flat_order_item'), '(r.child_id=s.product_id AND s.product_id IN(' . $sampleqry . ')) OR (s.product_id=e.entity_id)', array('SUM(s.qty_ordered) as qtyordered'));
                $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
                $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->order('qtyordered DESC');
```

Same code is working fine in Magento 1.4 but not in 1.7.0.2 
How can I fix this issue, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11808/using-magento-pagination-with-custom-collections

refer this answer

Comment: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-collection-paging

Comment: Actually, I am using above code for custom sorting. For all default sorting option it is working fine but not for my custom sorting option.

Comment: Above links are not much useful for me.

Comment: print your query and test your sorting order will apply in your query or not

Comment: Yes, I have printed my query and run same in mysql and it is giving correct result.

Comment: I have to do some RND

Comment: I am also doing same, please post here if you find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you apply group on collection magento collection counts gets break, this i had fixed by using below code.

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php

protected function _getSelectCountSql($select = null, $resetLeftJoins = true)
    {
       $this->_renderFilters();
       $countSelect = (is_null($select)) ?
           $this->_getClearSelect() :
           $this->_buildClearSelect($select);


       if(count($countSelect->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
           $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
       }


       $countSelect->columns('COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id)');
       if ($resetLeftJoins) {
           $countSelect->resetJoinLeft();
       }
       return $countSelect;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But can you let me know how did you figured it out.

Comment: year back i had created 1 extension for admin and i had did multiple joins and had used group also, at that time i had done extensive research on this and had came across with these solution :)

Comment: welcome buddy..